# Python not reading/extracting gzip file because...compression is too high?

Tags: python, search, gzip, zcat

This is code I'm working on to search for patterns in a tar.gz then output the files found out.

Earlier I had a question similar to this, but I've figured out the problem- when I pass in a tar.gz file that has been compressed to level 9, python returns a null pointer type error- I believe the culprit lies in the high compression level, because this code works when I pass in a regular parameter-less
tar.gz file...

So, I tried to do a gzip.open, but it didn't extract the file properly...I'm trying to figure out other ways to search and retrieve files with patterns without unzipping the whole thing as that would cost a lot of unnecessary space to be used up. Would streaming a zcat from the gzip file work, for example?

Here's a snippet of some of the code I've worked on

```
tar = tarfile.open(tarName, 'r:gz')
#tar = gzip.open(tarName, 'rb')
#tar = tarfile.open(sys.stdin.read(), 'r')

directory = directoryname+'/'
if not os.path.exists(directory) and not (param1 == 2):
    os.makedirs(directory)

start = time.time()
numTotal = 0;
numFound = 0;

#case 1: look for string anywhere
if (param2 == 0):

    for currentFile in tar:
        numTotal+=1;
        x=tar.extractfile(currentFile)

        if stringCheck in x.read():

          numFound +=1

          if (param1 == 2):
        continue

          new = open(directory + ntpath.basename(currentFile.name), 'w');
          x.seek(0,0)
          new.write( x.read() )
          new.close()
          if (param1 == 1):
            print "Instance found at " + currentFile.name
```